# A query on $F$-homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K/F$ be a field extension and $S=\{ s_1,\ldots , s_m\}\subset K$.

Does there exist a unique $F$-homomorphism $\psi: F[t_i]_{i=1}^m\to F[S]$ s.t $\psi(t_i)=s_i$?
Does there exist a unique $F$-homomorphism $\psi: F(t_i)_{i=1}^m\to F(S)$ s.t $\psi(t_i)=s_i$?

I think that the answer to the first question is yes and to the second that no; but I am not sure how to prove it?

Any input on this question?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes: it is the universal property of polynomial rings.

As far as the other part is concerned, I assume that $F(t_1,\dots,t_m)$ is the ring of quotients of $F[t_1,\dots,t_m]$. Then $\psi$ can be extended to a homomorphism $F(t_1,\dots,t_m)\to F(S)$ (the codomain is the ring of quotients of $F[S]$) if and only if it is injective.

If you want a specific counterexample, take $m=1$ and $s_1=0$.